# Correct usage of MVVM and object for method

Tags: c#, object-oriented, mvvm

I'm writing my first C# Windows Store app and am learning C# from scratch. I'm trying to implement MVVM as I understand it and object orientated patterns, obviously though I'm expecting to be doing it wrong so looking for pointers as to what I should improve.

Below is a method that gets called when a user either clicks a 'Search' XAML control, or hits return in the search textbox control.

The comments should explain the code. I feel like I probably have too much code in for a event method so please advise how I would restructure it.

```
  private void SubmitSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //New Validation object
        ViewModels.Validation validation = new ViewModels.Validation();

        // Capture user entered term and check is valid
        // submit appropriate message. 
        var searchValue = searchTerm.Text.ToString();
        dynamic validateInput = validation.inputNullCheck(searchValue);

        int? errorCode = validateInput.ErrorCode;

        if (errorCode == 0)
        {
            SubmitAction(searchValue);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayTerms(validateInput);
        }

    }
```

My SubmitAction method:

```
public async Task<object> SubmitAction(string searchValue)
    {

        // Query webservice/database through Model and return response
        dynamic response = await new ViewModels.Search().QueryRequest(searchValue);
        DisplayTerms(response);

        //This is here only because I needed the method to be async, which in turn requires a
        // value to be returned. Ideally it would be async and end after DisplayTerms(response);
        return response;
    }
```

DisplayTerms method:

```
private void DisplayTerms(object value)
    {

        ListView termsList = termsListContainer;
        dynamic searchResponse = value;

        int count = searchResponse.Count;

        // This will eventually be a loop through the returned object
        // it is hardcoded at the moment because I am debugging something. 
        termsList.Items.Add(searchResponse[0].TermName);
    }
```

Validation class:

```
class Validation
{

    // Temporarily 0 = success, 1 = error
    public int? ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorName { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    //Constructor    
    public Validation ()
    {

    }

    // Check if user input was empty
    public object inputNullCheck(string input)
    {
        if (input != "")
        {
            this.ErrorCode = 0;
            this.ErrorName = "Success";
            this.ErrorMessage = "Valid input received";
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ErrorCode = 1;
            this.ErrorName = "Input Empty";
            this.ErrorMessage = "You have not input anything.";
            return this; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify why you are using `dynamic` instead of a concrete type?

Comment: I'm not on my PC right now, but fairly certain when I tried a concrete type it gave me an error. I will have to check my code tomorrow and let you know I'm unfortunately away from my PC until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Class Validation**

- you can omit the empty constructor. If a class contains no constructor the compiler will add a default parameterless one.
- the properties setters should be either `private` or `protected`
- `nullable int` as error code does not make sense, at least based on your implementation.
- `public object inputNullCheck(string input)`

  - this method implies by it's name that it is checking if `input == null`. But it checks if `input != ""`. Also for readability always check against `String.Empty`.
  - passing `null` to this method leads to `Success` because `null != ""`
  - instead of returning `object` you should return `Validation`
  - instead of checking if `ErrorCode == 0` for success you should provide a property `Boolean HasError`.
  - for input which is not null and not empty you shouldn't set the properties
- Refactored

  ```
  class ErrorConstants
  {
      public const int EmptyInput = 1;
      public const int NullInput = 2;
  }
  class Validation
  {
      public int? ErrorCode { get; private set; }
      public string ErrorName { get; private set; }
      public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

      public Boolean HasError { get { return ErrorCode.HasValue; } }

      public Validation ValidateInput(string input)
      {
          if (input == null)
          {
              this.ErrorCode = ErrorConstants.NullInput;
              this.ErrorName = "Input null";
              this.ErrorMessage = "Given input is null.";
          }
          else if (input.Length == 0)
          {
              this.ErrorCode = ErrorConstants.EmptyInput;
              this.ErrorName = "Input Empty";
              this.ErrorMessage = "You have not input anything.";
          }
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```

**`private void SubmitSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`**

As `searchTerm` has a `Text` property this property will return a String, so calling `ToString()` is obsolete.

Implementing the changes above this will look like

```
private void SubmitSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    ViewModels.Validation validation = new ViewModels.Validation();

    var searchValue = searchTerm.Text;

    if (validation.inputNullCheck(searchValue).HasError)
    {
        DisplayTerms(validation);
    }
    else
    {
        SubmitAction(searchValue);            
    }
}
```

**You shouldn't call `DisplayTerms()` here, as this will for sure throw an exception, beacuse a `string` does not have a property ´Count`.**

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)

- classes, methods and properties should be named using `PascalCase` casing -> `inputNullCheck()`
- method names should be made out of verbs or verb phrases -> `inputNullCheck()`

**General**

- Comments should describe **why** something is done. Describing **what** is done should be done by the code itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've just got around to reviewing this and it is very helpful. Everything seems to make sense to me, although until you mentioned it I though of null and empty as the same (which I now know is incorrect).

Answer (score 4):

Minor note:

Here in your validation class there's this comment.

> ```
> // Temporarily 0 = success, 1 = error
> ```

Which is fine. You don't want to use a boolean because you'll be adding more status codes in the future. Cool! But you *shouldn't* be hard coding the error code numbers. This is what [enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) are for.

```
enum ValidationStatus {Success,GenericError}

// Check if user input was empty
public object inputNullCheck(string input)
{
    if (input != "")
    {
        this.ErrorCode = ValidationStatus.Success;
```

At this point, it would be better to remove this code

> ```
>        this.ErrorName = "Success";
>        this.ErrorMessage = "Valid input received";
> ```

And create a class that manages what Message to return based off of the value of the `ValidationStatus` passed into its constructor.

Reducing the above code to

```
    if (input != "")
    {
        return new ValidationResult(ValidationStatus.Success);
```

Comment: Thanks for this too, much appreciated. I haven't used enums before but I will look into their benefits for both this and further usage.

Comment: You're very welcome @James! I'm glad I could help.